# Show remote desktop rdp filename in connection bar

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

When I connect to a remote desktop using IP address instead of server name, the IP address is displayed in the connection bar in fullscreen mode, and in the window title when in window mode. This is natural.

If I store the connection details in an `.rdp` file, the name of the file is also displayed in window mode, but not in fullscreen mode.

[image: Connection in window mode opened through an RDP-file called "RDP-Connection.rdp"]
<sup>Connection in window mode opened through an RDP-file with name `RDP-Connection.rdp`.</sup>

[image: IP Address in connection bar]
<sup>Same connection in fullscreen mode - showing only the IP, not the file name.</sup>

Is it possible to get the RDP file name shown in the connection bar in fullscreen mode? It will be helpful when working with many connections, and I want to see with a quick look which connection I have active.
I am not good at recognizing IP addresses...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is possible, but a workaround would be to add those IPs in your `hosts` file.

For example :

```
host1    10.253.0.178
host2    10.253.1.140
```

Then you could store the connections in a .rdp file containing the hostname of the machine. It should be displayed in the fullscreen bar.

Comment: Very good idea! Unfortunately it did not work... Remote Desktop didn't find it. :(

Comment: Have you tried a `nslookup` to see if hostnames resolve to correct IPs?

Comment: the solution works (windows 10). You need to execute `notepad C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` from an administrator cmd